# Are Islam and classless society mutually exclusive?

Tags: quran, politics

Are classless societies and Islam mutually exclusive? I believe that this is one of the major hurdles of communism; that the only easy way to remove socioreligious classes would be to ban religion, but that would cause much fight-back. So has anybody come up with a non-atheistic alternative to the problem of religion in communism? Does the Quran say anything, not necessarily about communism, but about class hierarchy?

See also [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10485/how-can-a-classless-society-exist-with-religion) at politics se (there are links to more questions at other religious sites there).

Comment: Do you share the philosophical premises of Marxist sociology? You seem to classify the religious castes as a class in the Marxist sense of the term and that implies the Marxist understanding of religion as an ideology which works to disguise/legitimize the economic class interests of the religious caste in the name of Divine right.  If that's so, any genuine Islamic answer to your question would have to start with a critique of Marxist philosophy and its view of the nature of religion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your question.

Basically, I would say that Islam and a classless society could exist, simultaneously.

... ...

Throughout my studies, I have come to the conclusion that Islam proposes an economic system, which is unique among capitalism and communism. It could be called: an asset-based model of society.

This model has two elements of capitalism: (a) the right to private property; and (b) the right to earn, and keep, as much wealth as one would like.

What differentiates this model from capitalism, is that Islam prohibits usury.

Furthermore, debt is strongly discouraged in Islam. So, the question would naturally arise (from people who invest in interest-based ventures): What would I do with any extra money, if I cannot invest it in an interest-bearing security?

The answer, would be one of three things.

Firstly, an individual, in my opinion, should have enough wealth saved up to provide for one year of living expenses. Actually, the Prophet - peace and blessings of Allah be upon him - did something similar. Though, he had non-perishable food items as well (which are, in fact, a substitute for money, and can be traded themselves). Where I live, one year's living expenses would be about $24,000.

... ...

Secondly, we see that Islam advocates an "asset-based" model of economics. Debt, on the other hand, is a liability.

An asset could be defined as something which you own - meaning, that if you were to suddenly suffer a health-related injury, and were unable to earn money from your regular job, you would nevertheless have no fear of losing what you own, because you do not owe any payments on it. (Think, for example, about person who goes into debt for a $100,000 home, or a $10,000 car). So, for the person who has extra money to invest, a next step (after having a year's worth of expenses saved up) would be to acquire assets which are more or less essential to one's way of life - land, housing, and a means of transportation.

I could say more about this subject, but I figured that this would be sufficient by way of an introduction.

Comment: Your raise valid points in regards with debt and usury, but I think your statement that Islam allows "the right to earn, and keep, as much wealth as one would like" is inconsistent with Islamic condemnation of *takathur* which is concentration of wealth by individuals beyond their basic needs.